# Inserted div text to input field and need to know if div is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#form input[id=Amount]').val(parseInt($('#eventamount').text()));

<div id="eventamount">0</div>

    <div id="form">
    <input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="cat_textbox" value="" readonly="true" />
    </div>
```

Condition is if the div#eventamount is empty then hide the div#form or there is no div#eventamount exists then also hide the div#form?

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what you tried so far pls include js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="eventamount">0</div>

    <div id="form">
        <input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="cat_textbox" value="" readonly="true" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            if ($("#eventamount").text() == null || $("#eventamount").text() == "")
            {
                $("#form").hide();
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can try this

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#eventamount').text() == ''){
    //hides when eventamount container is empty
    $('#form').hide();

}
else{
    $('#form').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the element exists or not by `.length` property and to check whether element is empty or not use `.text()`

```
$(function () {
    var $eventamount = $("#eventamount");
    if ($eventamount.length==0 || $eventamount.text() == "")
        $("#form").hide();
})
```